# Calling gdalogr:gridinvdist in python console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to apply grid IDW interpolation to a point layer using python in QGIS, but I keep running into errors about one or more parameter values being incorrect... Should be a straightforward process but... What could be wrong?

```
import processing 
processing.runalg('gdalogr:gridinvdist', 
                        {"Input layer":"C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/shp/test.shp",
                        "Z field":"z",
                        "Power":2,
                        "smothing":0,
                        "Radius 1":4,
                        "Radius 2":5,
                        "Max points":6,
                        "Min points":1,
                        "angle": 0,
                        "nodata": 0,
                        "rtype": 5,
                        "Output file": "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/tif/test2.tif"})


>>> execfile(u'c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpskr43u.py'.encode('mbcs'))
Error: Wrong parameter value 6 for parameter Max points.
```

I've tried playing with the values but no luck, it would return same error with the new number I've input. I've also tried commenting out one or more parameters but still won't do the trick and would create other parameter errors.

Comment: @Vale Thanks for the input. Just tried but same error unfortunately. "Smothing" is also the parameter name given in the QGIS document lol

Comment: yes my fault I gave you a bad input sorry ;) checked myself too the documentation

Comment: you should try with full uppercase parameters name and use underscore than space, like that : 
                        {"INPUT":"",
                        "Z_FIELD":"z",
                        "POWER":2,
                        "SMOTHING":0,
                        "RADIUS_1":4,
                        "RADIUS_2":0.0,
                        "MAX_POINTS":2,
                        "MIN_POINTS":1,
                        "ANGLE": 0,
                        "NODATA": 0,
                        "RTYPE": 5,
                        "OUTPUT": ""})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, 
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/gridinvdist.html#console-usage

the parameters has to be named like that. Also you have to use uppercase to get it work.

```
import processing 
processing.runalg('gdalogr:gridinvdist', 
                    {"INPUT":"/Users/R/Desktop/test.shp",
                    "Z_FIELD":"z",
                    "POWER":2,
                    "SMOTHING":0,
                    "RADIUS_1":4,
                    "RADIUS_2":0.0,
                    "MAX_POINTS":2,
                    "MIN_POINTS":1,
                    "ANGLE": 0,
                    "NODATA": 0,
                    "RTYPE": 5,
                    "OUTPUT": "/Users/R/Desktop/test2.tif"})
```

Comment: Answer accepted because the capitals trick did work, though in the end it produced a complete black square in a different coordinate system from the project.. Perhaps I need to fiddle with the parameters and need to specify a CRS for the outcome.